# Android: RecyclerView in a ScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I'm trying to have a RecyclerView inside a ScrollView. My problem is that when i scroll the RecyclerView this is not "smooth": as soon as you release your finger the scrolling stops immediately.

My layout in the fragment is:

- Scrollview

  - LinearLayout

    - TextView
    - RecyclerView
    - Button

I tried disabling nested scrolling:

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)
```

and wrapping content of mRecyclerView:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

obtaining the smooth scrolling i wanted, but in this way the height of the RecyclerView is smaller than it should (and it doesn't scroll anymore, so i can't see some items).

I'm currently using support library 23.4.0 (i tried also 23.2.1, same problems)

Any help?

Comment: RecyclerView  has already scroll, why you need to put it in ScrollView ?

Comment: Use CoordinatorLayout instead of ScrollView.

Comment: I need a ScrollView because i don't have only the RecyclerView in my layout. I want the ScrollView to be the only View scrollable, but i need the RecyclerView to show all its content

Comment: Did you tried to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html) ? Also can you provide screenshot please !

Answer (score 1):

This problem has wrecked my night. :)

### Observations

When `RecyclerView` is on the first screen (visible without scrolling), preceding views impact its height. When `RecyclerView` is initially fully invisible (requires scrolling the whole screen down), its height is correct.

### Reason

When `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollView` measures its children, it passes how many pixels left as a `MeasureSpec` with mode `UNSPECIFIED`.
`RecyclerView` passes this spec to `LayoutManager`, and it obeys passed height, if it is not null, even it is `UNSPECIFIED`.

### Solution

Extend `RecyclerView` and override `RecyclerView#onMeasure` and, when height measure spec is `UNSPECIFIED`, just pass zero to `super.onMeasure`.

Java:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(
        widthSpec,
        MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? 0 : heightSpec
    )
}
```

Kotlin:

```
override fun onMeasure(widthSpec: Int, heightSpec: Int) {
    super.onMeasure(
        widthSpec,
        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) 0
        else heightSpec
    )
}
```