# RecyclerView is not trully wrap_content at the ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml

I have a `ScrollView,` which contains a vertical `LinearLayout.` This is a place, where I add some amount of Views called "Section". "Section" is a `LinearLayout,` which contains a `TextView` and `RecyclerView.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sections_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</ScrollView>
```

**section:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_starred_title_textsize" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that `RecyclerView` is not truly `wrap_content` sometimes. Therefore it creates 2 types of problems (depending on solution type I'm trying to use).

1. It can be unscrollable (so it matches  screen height and I can't scroll it down to see rest of items inside).
2. It can scroll nested.

Originally problem is that it has nested scrolling. So I want `RecyclerViews` to be as simple vertical `LinearLayouts` and the only thing that has to have scrolling effect is root `ScrollView.`

**What have I tried to do?**

1. extend the `GridLayoutManager` and override `canScrollVertically().` method:

   public boolean canScrollVertically(){
       return false;
   }
2. extend `RecyclerView` class and override

   @Override
   public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
       return false;
   }
3. Disable `NestedScrolling` via `xml` everywhere, where it is possible.
4. Override `GridLayoutManager` using this solution: [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35871165/set-height-of-inner-recyclerview-wrap-content)
5. Combine 1-4

Comment: Have you tried to replace ScrollView with NestedScrollView in your layout?

Comment: @Buckstabue no. I'll try now. Tnx

Comment: @Buckstabue helped! Not only by that but thanks anyway!

Comment: Similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267532/android-recyclerview-in-a-scrollview/48640711

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't use `RecyclerView` or `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. For nested scrolling you should use `NestedScrollView`.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting as
>   both a `nested` scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

**SOLUTION:**

**1.** Instead of using `ScrollView`, use `NestedScrollView` as container of your `Section` part(`RecyclerView` and other `Views`).

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sections_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Your Section:: RecyclerView and other Views -->

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

**2.** For scrolling issue use `setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to your `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score -2):

Solution is next:
1. Use NestedScrollView
2. Override GridLayoutManager.canScrollVertically():

```
public boolean canScrollVertically(){ return false; }
```